# How to interact with Google Contacts using XML and HTTP?

Tags: c#, http, google-contacts-api

I am trying to understand [this document](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#GettingStarted).

But I am not getting how to implement it in my previous code which I did according to [this link](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/1.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Creating) .

Can anyone provide me sample code to proceed with.

I am not getting how to use these XML entries.

Answer (score 1):

The [C# library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/) you're using in your 'previous code' is a wrapper around the Google Contacts API protocol, which is the document you're trying to understand. To be more precise, it's a wrapper around 
[the Google Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/) which Google Contacts provides.

The protocol are actually REST calls which return you ATOM and/or JSON feeds. You could implement this in C# using WebRequest and WebResponse and parse the result with something like XMLReader, but why would you do that if there's already a library which does that for you?

Comment: Because there are some properties (nickname,birthdate e.t.c) which cannot created by Version 2 DLL and Version 3 is not yet released.

Comment: Why not check out the source code, add support for the properties, and build your own version? 

And if you're feeling helpful, send Google a patch to support the missing properties.